# Remove dots from data column

Tags: r, regex

I'm beginner dealing with R and working with strings.
I've been trying to remove periods from data but unfortunately I can't find a solution.

This is the data I'm working on in a dataframe `df`:

```
df <- read.table(text = " n   mesAno          receita
                 97   1/2009 3.812.819.062,06
                 98   2/2009 4.039.362.599,36
                 99   3/2009 3.652.885.587,18
                 100  4/2009 3.460.247.960,02
                 101  5/2009 3.465.677.403,12
                 102  6/2009 3.131.903.622,55
                 103  7/2009 3.204.983.361,46
                 104  8/2009 3.811.786.009,24
                 105  9/2009 3.180.864.095,05
                 106 10/2009 3.352.535.553,88
                 107 11/2009 5.214.148.756,95
                 108 12/2009 4.491.795.201,50
                 109  1/2010 4.333.557.619,30
                 110  2/2010 4.808.488.277,86
                 111  3/2010 4.039.347.179,81
                 112  4/2010 3.867.676.530,69
                 113  5/2010 6.356.164.873,94
                 114  6/2010 3.961.793.391,19
                 115  7/2010    3797656130.81
                 116  8/2010    4709949715.37
                 117  9/2010    4047436592.12
                 118 10/2010    3923484635.28
                 119 11/2010    4821729985.03
                 120 12/2010    5024757038.22", 
header = TRUE, 
stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

My objective is to transform `receita` column to numeric as it's is being stored as factor. But applying conversion functions like `as.numeric(as.factor(x))` does not work in the interval 97:114 (it coerces to NA's).

I suppose that this is because of the periods separating billion/million/thousands in this column. 
The mentioned conversion functions will work only if I have something like `3812819062.06` as in 115:120.

I tried mutating the dataset adding another column and modelling. 
I don't really know if what i'm doing is fine, but i also tried extracting the anomalous numbers to a variable, and applying sub/gsub on them but without success.

Is there some straight forward way of doing this, that is, instruct it to remove the 2 first occurrences of '.' and then replace the comma with a '.'?
I'm very confident that the function i'm needing is `gsub` but i'm having a hard time finding the correct usage. Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: My approach using `dplyr::mutate()`. Ugly but works.

```
df <- df %>% 
mutate(receita_temp = receita) %>% 
mutate(dot_count = str_count(receita, '\\.')) %>% 
mutate(receita_temp = ifelse(dot_count == 3, 
                             gsub('\\.', '', as.factor(receita_temp)), 
                             gsub('\\,', '.',as.factor(receita_temp))
                             )) %>% 
mutate(receita_temp = ifelse(dot_count == 3,
                             gsub('\\,', '.',as.factor(receita_temp)),
                                  receita_temp)) %>% 
select(-c(dot_count, receita)) %>% 
rename(., receita = receita_temp)
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a function that will do this more prettily, but you could always use `gsub` twice on the first 114 rows.  Substitute "." for "" the first time, "," for "." the second and you'll be left with numbers matching your later entries.  Just make sure you don't apply it to the whole column or you'll mess up the ones that are already formatted properly

Comment: Please add the code you tried to mutate the text.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, added as an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:
first create a function that will be used for replacement:

```
repl = function(x)setNames(c("","."),c(".",","))[x]
```

This function takes in either `"."` or `","` and returns `""` or `'.'` respectively

Now use this function to replace

```
stringr::str_replace_all(as.character(df[,3]), "[.](?!\\d+$)|,", repl)

[1] "3812819062.06" "4039362599.36" "3652885587.18" "3460247960.02" "3465677403.12" "3131903622.55"
[7] "3204983361.46" "3811786009.24" "3180864095.05" "3352535553.88" "5214148756.95" "4491795201.50"
[13] "4333557619.30" "4808488277.86" "4039347179.81" "3867676530.69" "6356164873.94" "3961793391.19"
[19] "3797656130.81" "4709949715.37" "4047436592.12" "3923484635.28" "4821729985.03" "5024757038.22"
```

Of course you can do the rest. ie calling `as.numeric()` etc.

To do this in base R:

```
sub(',','.',gsub('[.](?!\\d+$)','',as.character(df[,3]),perl=T))
```

or If you know the exact number of `.` and `,` in your data, you could do

```
a = as.character(df[,3])
regmatches(a,gregexpr('[.](?!\\d+$)|,',df[,3],perl = T)) = list(c("","","","."))
a
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using regex and some `stringr` functions to remove all the periods except those followed by two digits and the end of the string. That way, periods denoting separation like in `3.811.786.009,24` are removed, but periods denoting the start of a decimal like in `4821729985.03` are not. Using `str_remove_all` rather than `str_remove` lets me not have to worry about removing the matches repeatedly or about how well it will scale. Then replace the remaining commas with periods, and make it numeric.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(receita = str_remove_all(receita, "\\.(?!\\d{2,}$)") %>% 
           str_replace_all(",", ".") %>%
           as.numeric())

print(head(df2), digits = 12)
#>     n mesAno       receita
#> 1  97 1/2009 3812819062.06
#> 2  98 2/2009 4039362599.36
#> 3  99 3/2009 3652885587.18
#> 4 100 4/2009 3460247960.02
#> 5 101 5/2009 3465677403.12
#> 6 102 6/2009 3131903622.55
```

Created on 2018-09-04 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

```
df$num <- as.numeric(sapply(as.character(si), function(x) gsub("\\,","\\.",ifelse(grepl("\\,", x), gsub("\\.","",x),x))))
```

should do the trick.

First, the function searches for rows with ",", removes "." in these rows, and last it converts all occurring "," into ".", so that it can be converted without problems to numeric.

Use `print(df$num, digits = 12)` to see your data with 2 decimals.